# Splitting Strings in SAS

Tags: sas

I have values in a variable that look like:

```
B1234
A0345
C65405
```

I want to split it so that it so that it will appear as the first 3 characters followed by everything else as shown below.

```
B1234: B12 34
A0345: A03 45
C65405: C65 405
```

Is there any way I can do this in SAS

Thanks!

Comment: Are these variables or variable values? If these are variables, do you mean that you want to have a variable with a name containing a space character?

Comment: Do you want to create two new variables? Or just insert a space before the 4th character of the current variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr()` and concatenate them.

```
data want;
    var = 'B1234';
    split = catx(' ', substr(var, 1, 3), substr(var, 4) );
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution suggested by Stu with substr is the easiest, but you can also do it using regexes:

```
result = prxChange('s/^(.{3})(.*)/$1 $2/', -1, trim(source));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` statement, or an `IF` statement

```
where item_code like 'B1%'
```

or

```
if item_code =: 'B1'
```

There are other ways but you haven't explained the situation in more detail

Comment: % wildcards with `if` won't work, and the `=:` operator - "begins with" - wouldn't need a trailing wildcard anyway.